# Specific case in Julia Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I need to do something quite specific and i'm trying to do it the good way , especially i want it to be optimized .

So i have a DataFrame that look like this :

```
│ Row      │ USER_ID │ GENRE_MAIN        │ ALBUM_NAME                                                                  │ ALBUM_ARTIST_NAME              │ TOTAL_LISTENED │ TOTAL_COUNT_LISTENED │
│          │ String  │ String            │ String                                                                      │ String                         │ DecFP.Dec128   │ DecFP.Dec128         │
├──────────┼─────────┼───────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ 1        │ 9s2dsdd6  │ ROCK              │ The Thought's Boy                                                       │ AARON MADISON                  │ 5912.0         │ 91.0                 │
│ 1        │ 9s2dsdd6  │ ROCK              │ The wqeqwewe                                                          │ AARON MADISON                  │ 3212.0         │ 91.0                 │
│ 2        │ 11sdasd63 │ ROCK              │ Down On The Upside                                                          │ SOUNDGARDEN                    │ 3354.0         │ 14.0                 │
│ 3        │ 112sds334 │ CLASSICAL         │ Beethoven: Symphonies Nos. 1 & 2 - C.P.E. Bach: Symphonies, Wq 175 & 183/17 │ AKADEMIE FÜR ALTE MUSIK BERLIN │ 1372.0         │ 4.0                  │
│ 4        │ 145sdsd42 │ POP               │ My Life in the Bush of Ghosts                                               │ BRIAN ENO                      │ 3531.0         │ 17.0                 │
```

I want to aggregate it by user (i have many rows per user_id ) and do many calculations
I'm doing aggregation with this :

```
gdf = DataFrames.groupby(df, :USER_ID)
combine(gdf,:TOTAL_LISTENED => sum => :TOTAL_SECONDS_LISTENED,
            :TOTAL_COUNT_LISTENED => sum => :TOTAL_TRACKS_LISTENED)
```

I need to calculate the top 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 genre, album name, artist name per user_id and it has to be like this :

```
USER_ID │ ALBUM1_NAME      │ ALBUM2_NAME  ......│ GENRE1       │ GENRE2
```

One line per user_id .

So i tried to do it with a countmap and then sort it , keep only the top 5 , and assign each value to a column in a Dataframe

```
transposed = sort(countmap(targetId[targetCol]), byvalue=true, rev=true) 

for (i, g) in enumerate(eachcol(transposed))
        rVal["ALBUM$(i)_NAME"] = g[1]
        rVal["ALBUM$(i)_ARTIST"] = g[3]
        rVal["ALBUM$(i)_TIME"] = g[2]
        rVal["ALBUM$(i)_ID"] = "ID"
        rVal["USER_ID"] = id
    end
```

but it doesn't work in a combine , its just very ugly and im sure i can do it a better way .

I hope its understandable , if someone can help me please =)

Thank you

EDIT : A way to reproduce the DataFrame:

```
v = ["x","y","z"][rand(1:3, 10)]
df = DataFrame(Any[collect(1:10), v, rand(10)], [:USER_ID, :GENRE_MAIN, :TOTAL_LISTENED])
```

Comment: your EDIT contains different variable names so my solution will not work on it as it uses your original variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not provided an easy way to reproduce your source data, so I am writing the solution from my head and hope I have not made any typo (note that you need DataFrames.jl 0.22 for this to work, while you seem to be on some older version of the package):

```
using DataFrames, Pipe, Random, Pkg

Pkg.activate(".")
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("Pipe")

Random.seed!(1234)

df = DataFrame(USER_ID=rand(1:10, 80),
               GENRE_MAIN=rand(string.("genre_", 1:6), 80),
               ALBUM_NAME=rand(string.("album_", 1:6), 80),
               ALBUM_ARTIST_NAME=rand(string.("artist_", 1:6), 80))

function top5(sdf, col, prefix)
    return @pipe groupby(sdf, col) |>
                 combine(_, nrow) |>
                 sort!(_, :nrow, rev=true) |>
                 first(_, 5) |>
                 vcat(_[!, 1], fill(missing, 5 - nrow(_))) |>
                 DataFrame([string(prefix, i) for i in 1:5] .=> _)
end

@pipe groupby(df, :USER_ID) |>
      combine(_,
              x -> top5(x, :GENRE_MAIN, "genre"),
              x -> top5(x, :ALBUM_NAME, "album"), 
              x -> top5(x, :ALBUM_ARTIST_NAME, "artist"))
```

The code is a bit complex as we have to handle the fact that there might be less than 5 entries per group.

It produces under Julia 1.5.3:

```
10×16 DataFrame
 Row │ USER_ID  genre1   genre2   genre3   genre4   genre5   album1   album2   album3   album4   album5   artist1   artist2   artist3   artist4   artist5
     │ Int64    String   String   String   String?  String?  String   String   String   String   String?  String    String    String    String?   String?
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │       1  genre_1  genre_3  genre_5  genre_2  genre_4  album_3  album_5  album_6  album_1  album_4  artist_1  artist_4  artist_3  artist_2  artist_6
   2 │       4  genre_1  genre_3  genre_6  genre_2  missing  album_2  album_4  album_5  album_6  missing  artist_4  artist_5  artist_2  missing   missing
   3 │       8  genre_2  genre_1  genre_6  genre_5  missing  album_1  album_5  album_4  album_2  missing  artist_5  artist_6  artist_4  artist_1  artist_3
   4 │       2  genre_1  genre_5  genre_2  genre_4  genre_3  album_6  album_3  album_4  album_2  album_1  artist_4  artist_2  artist_6  artist_1  artist_5
   5 │      10  genre_5  genre_3  genre_6  genre_4  genre_2  album_2  album_3  album_1  album_5  album_4  artist_1  artist_6  artist_2  artist_5  artist_3
   6 │       7  genre_5  genre_3  genre_2  genre_4  genre_1  album_2  album_4  album_3  album_5  missing  artist_4  artist_1  artist_3  artist_5  missing
   7 │       9  genre_3  genre_4  genre_2  missing  missing  album_1  album_3  album_4  album_2  missing  artist_4  artist_2  artist_6  artist_3  missing
   8 │       5  genre_2  genre_3  genre_4  genre_6  missing  album_2  album_1  album_3  album_4  missing  artist_6  artist_5  artist_4  artist_1  missing
   9 │       3  genre_6  genre_5  genre_4  genre_2  genre_1  album_3  album_4  album_1  album_5  missing  artist_4  artist_3  artist_6  artist_5  missing
  10 │       6  genre_3  genre_4  genre_1  genre_6  missing  album_2  album_4  album_5  album_3  missing  artist_4  artist_6  artist_5  missing   missing
```

which I assume you wanted?

Comment: Yes sorry i'll edit the question with a better source data , i get ERROR: MethodError: no method matching combine(::GroupedDataFrame{DataFrame}, ::var"#19#22", ::var"#20#23", ::var"#21#24") when i try to do your solution do you know why ?

Comment: Yes - I know - you are not on DataFrames.jl 0.22 - see the comment I have given in the answer. Please update the package to its latest version first.

Comment: Im so sorry , ok

Comment: I still have the same error even with dataframe 0.22 =( (i did a add DataFrame#master)

Comment: I have checked - my code was correct. I am copy-pasting a full reproducible solution. It is run under Julia 1.5.3.

Comment: Yes i had to upgrade julia as well , but now it works , thank you very much its very neat

Comment: I still have a little problem tho .
I need to add the corresponding total_listened  row alongside each col
So genre1 , i need genre1_total_listened
I don't really understand what the vcat do ( i think its for the case where there isnt 5 values but i can't manage to modify the vcat and the last line to add the total_listened)

Comment: Can you please open another question with a reproducible input and an example of output you want to make sure that I understand exactly what you want? It would be best if you focused in the new question on the specific issue you want to solve (so that the question on SO is focused on one thing). Thank you!

Comment: yes sure , sorry and thank you again 
Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168149/julia-dataframe-combine-specific-calculations-and-tranpose